# Ignore unregistered subtypes in RuntimeTypeAdapterFactory

Tags: java, android, json, gson, retrofit

We have a Retrofit API using GSON as the converter, and it makes a call for a list of cards to display to the user. A card follows this format:

```
[
    {
        "cardType": "user",
        "data": {}
    },
    {
        "cardType": "content",
        "data": {}
    }
]
```

The `data` property varies between cards, so to resolve this we use GSON's `RuntimeTypeAdapterFactory`:

```
final RuntimeTypeAdapterFactory<Card> factory = RuntimeTypeAdapterFactory
        .of(Card.class, "cardType")
        .registerSubtype(UserCard.class, "user")
        ...
        .registerSubtype(ContentCard.class, "content");
```

However, we've found that if the API is updated to include a *new* cardType that we aren't expecting, this silently fails to deserialize. By silently I mean, `response.isSuccessful()` still returns true, but the `response.body()` is null. The only way we were able to determine the new card type was the problem was through trial and error.

Is there any way to have GSON ignore any cardTypes that we haven't registered? If we try to add this new card but the app can't support it I would like to just ignore it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think that the problem is due the fact that `RuntimeTypeAdapterFactory` will throw an exception when trying to create adapter for unregistered type name (see excerpt from `RuntimeTypeAdapterFactory`s source code):

```
public <R> TypeAdapter<R> create(Gson gson, TypeToken<R> type) {
    ...

    // typeFieldName is the type name that is given when registering the sub type
    if (jsonObject.has(typeFieldName)) {
        throw new JsonParseException("cannot serialize " + srcType.getName()
            + " because it already defines a field named " + typeFieldName);
    }

    ...
}
```

This might lead `Retrofit` to truncate the whole response to `null`.

Then see the declaration of `TypeAdapterFactory`:

```
public interface TypeAdapterFactory {
    /**
    * Returns a type adapter for {@code type}, or null if this factory doesn't
    * support {@code type}.
    */
    <T> TypeAdapter<T> create(Gson gson, TypeToken<T> type);
}
```

If you were able to return `null` instead of throwing that exception I guess `Retrofit` could return all the sub classes it recognises.

This would be easy to handle by extending `RuntimeTypeAdapterFactory` and overriding the problematic method but unfortunately class is declared as `final`.

So you can either create a wrapping type adapter that calls the original RuntimeTypeAdapter inside it or as I would do it just copy the source for the class `RuntimeTypeAdapterFactory` in to some package of your own and edit it correspoding your needs. It is Open Source. So the problematic part would be like:

```
if (jsonObject.has(typeFieldName)) {
    log.warn("cannot serialize " + srcType.getName()
            + " because it already defines a field named " + typeFieldName);
    return null;
}
```

To clarify, because you are now returning `null` instead of throwing, your list will contain this null element. To truly ignore it, make sure you call `list.filterNotNull()` at the implementation.

Comment: Hey, wanna give an update as to why I haven't accepted this yet! I tried implementing this ourself, with your change, and it worked! Instead of forcing this change, I made the constructor accept a `forceRegisteredSubtypes` boolean. I tried writing unit tests around it and had unrelated Android Studio issues. Once I can unit test it and verify we don't need to make additional updates to the answer, I'll mark it as accepted. I just don't want to confuse any readers until I'm certain.

Comment: @AdamMc331 Thanks for the update & feedback. You could also remove the `final` modifier from the original source and inherit `RuntimeTypeAdapterFactory`. Then it might be more clear to override all the unwanted behaviour.

Comment: This worked! Going to add a little clarification on to the end of the answer here. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 1):

We had a similar problem but GSON wasn't so silent. We were hitting the error:

> cannot deserialize X subtype named Y; did you forget to register a
>   subtype?

To implement @pirho 's solution we copied `RuntimeTypeAdapterFactory` into our project.

1.) add a new field

```
private final Map<String, Class<?>> labelToSubtype = new LinkedHashMap<String, Class<?>>();
private final Map<Class<?>, String> subtypeToLabel = new LinkedHashMap<Class<?>, String>();
private final List<String> labelsToIgnore = new ArrayList<>(); // ADD THIS LINE
```

2.) add a new method:

```
public RuntimeTypeAdapterFactory<T> ignoreSubtype(String label) {
    labelsToIgnore.add(label);
    return this;
}
```

3.) update the `read` method in the `TypeAdapter`:

```
public R read(final JsonReader in) {
    JsonElement jsonElement = Streams.parse(in);
    JsonElement labelJsonElement = jsonElement.getAsJsonObject().remove(typeFieldName);
    if (labelJsonElement == null) {
        throw new JsonParseException("cannot deserialize " + baseType
                + " because it does not define a field named " + typeFieldName);
    }
    String label = labelJsonElement.getAsString();
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked") // registration requires that subtype extends T
            TypeAdapter<R> delegate = (TypeAdapter<R>) labelToDelegate.get(label);
    if (delegate == null) {
        // ------------- ADD THIS:
        if (labelsToIgnore.contains(label)) {
            return null;
        } else {
            throw new JsonParseException("cannot deserialize " + baseType + " subtype named "
                    + label + "; did you forget to register a subtype?");
        }
        // -------------
    }
    return delegate.fromJsonTree(jsonElement);
}
```

Finally use it like:

```
RuntimeTypeAdapterFactory<BaseClass> myTypeAdapterFactory 
= RuntimeTypeAdapterFactory
                .of(BaseClass.class, "type")
                .ignoreSubtype("type to ignore") // ADD THIS LINE
                .registerSubtype(SubtypeA.class, "type_a")
                .registerSubtype(SubtypeB.class, "type_b");          
                ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Beloved **Me**,

If you got here again - find `RequestSerializer` and add a `registerSubtype(SomeImportant.class)` there